# How do I optimize a polymorphic news feed in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, feed

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :requests

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :object, :polymorphic => true
```

I want to get all the users activities and display them

```
Activity.where(:user_id => current_user.id).include(:object)
```

the problem is that I can't eager load the object model because it's polymorphic
How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: I can use includes with a similar polymorphic association (Rails 3.1). What happens when you try?

Comment: Also a word of caution: If you testing this on Rails console to look at the sql generated (to conclude its not eager loading), then make sure you use a property on the object in your where clause or your select clause. Rails might be not eager loading as a optimization to the query (when not needed, at least I think its an optimization).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eager loading is supported with polymorphic associations. You will need to do something along the following lines:

```
Activity.find(:all, :include => :objectable, :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id})
```

Although you need to make sure that you have defined the polymorphic relationship correctly on the associated models.

For further help refer to:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations

The polymorphic part is at the end of "Eager loading of Associations" section.

Answer (score 2):

As @Wahaj says, eager loading only works with `:includes` and not `:join`.

Here's the explanation from the docs:

> Address.find(:all, :include => :addressable)
>
> This will execute one query to load the addresses and load the addressables with one query per addressable type. For example if all the addressables are either of class Person or Company then a total of 3 queries will be executed. The list of addressable types to load is determined on the back of the addresses loaded. This is not supported if Active Record has to fallback to the previous implementation of eager loading and will raise ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError. The reason is that the parent model’s type is a column value so its corresponding table name cannot be put in the FROM/JOIN clauses of that query.

I think this is what you're after:

```
current_user.activities.includes(:object)
```

As the docs say, there will be an extra query for each association. I'm not sure, but you may need to define an association the other direction for rails to know which AR models to search, eg:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, :as => :object
end
```

If you're still getting an error, you might be on an earlier rails version which hadn't yet implemented this.

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible to have eager loading to the Polymorphic relationship ... but u can do it for one polymorphic type like if u r having two polymorphic_type then filter the records on that type and then make eager loading it will work then .... not the perfect eager loading but partial eager loading